German Tax - Is "Verlustvortrag" Mandatory?
I'm hoping to get some clarity on a question I've been struggling to find an answer to. I appreciate any help.
In 2022, I reported a loss of -800 EUR from crypto sales (Anlage SO, 42: Kryptoverkäufe, 48: -800).

Am I required to submit a tax declaration for 2023 because of this loss? Do I have the option to not carry forward this loss and skip filing a return for 2023?
I had no other taxable income in 2023 (not even a salary), and it would be simpler for me to just forgo this loss and avoid filing a tax declaration.

Was it even necessary to declare this loss in 2022 in the first place? Would it have been legal for me to report 0 loss/profit from crypto sales in my 2022 tax declaration?


Thank you for your assistance.

Should this be on Personal Finance Stack Exchange?
